# Should a Makefile delete itself on 'make clean'?

Tags: makefile, posix, configure

I have a `configure` script that writes a Makefile (from `Makefile.in`). The `clean` target currently removes everything created from within the makefile, but it doesn't delete the makefile itself. (I'm not using Autotools as you can probably tell)

My question therefore: Should the makefile also remove itself, requiring the developer to run `./configure` again?

On the one hand, I want the clean target to properly clean up the source tree. But, on the other hand, I'd like to be able to type `make clean test` to check that everything's working as it should before committing; Running the configure script again *seems* weird somehow.

Comment: That totally depends on what you want to accomplish.  If the makefile is there for the sole purpose of executing the script, then delete the makefile.  If you want to leave the makefile for developers to use later, or for auditing purposes, then don't delete it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a stylistic question, rather than a technical question.  The best place to go for answers is the [automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html), which will tell you:

```
`make clean'
     Erase from the build tree the files built by `make all'.

`make distclean'
     Additionally erase anything `./configure' created.
```

So, no, `make clean` should not delete `Makefile`.  `make distclean` should delete `Makefile`, since it's created by `configure` not `make all`.

One of the best things about autotools is that they are *consistent* and *standard*.  It's best to not irritate your users by flouting those standards.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably have a separate target for that. So `clean` would leave them able to build again but `distclean` or `realclean` or `allclean` or something would force a reconfigure. You could see which autotools clean target (if any) has similar behaviour.

Comment: [The GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) mention `distclean` and `maintainer-clean`. However, I don't understand think I understand the text in relation to my question. (add.: not until reading MadScientist's answer)

Comment: `maintainer-clean` is only used by people who are running autoconf to generate configure scripts.  It's used to remove all files generated by autotools, which includes `configure` itself, plus other things.  Often that target is not even included in makefiles that are shipped with the source packages, and is only available if you get the code directly from the source control system and build it there (often projects will not check in autoconf output as source files, so you must have autotools installed to build from SCM).

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the clean target is usually to remove interim files, so you can start your compile from scratch. See more [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/makefiles.html)

> For instance, a common makefile target is "clean," which generally performs actions that clean up after the compiler--removing object files and the resulting executable.